# Bootstrap 4 scrollspy with list-group doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement [Scrollspy with list group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#example-with-list-group) in Bootstrap 4, but it doesn't work. Scroll content contains `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#fixed-menu" data-offset="0"` and menu contains `id="fixed-menu"`.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/26150/)

**html**

```
<main class="Site-content">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="container-full">
      <div class="row ml-1">
        <div className="col col-10 ml-1" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#fixed-menu" data-offset="0">
        <h3>Create</h3>
        <div id="main1" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Main1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main2" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Main2</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main3" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Main3</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main4" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Main4</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div
       id="fixed-menu"
       class="list-group fixedMenu"
       >
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action listItem__link d-flex py-2 px-3" href="#main1">
                Main1
              </a>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action listItem__link d-flex py-2 px-3" href="#main2">
                Main2
              </a>
              <a
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action listItem__link d-flex py-2 px-3"
                href="#main3"
              >
                Main3
              </a>
              <a
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action listItem__link d-flex py-2 px-3"
                href="#main4"
              >
                Main4
              </a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**css**

```
.Site-content{
  flex: 1;
}

.fixedMenu{
  width: 110px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you write it as an answer and I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/scrollspy/#via-data-attributes), use the appropriate data attributes on the parent of the scrollspy element...

`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#fixed-menu" data-offset="0">`

Comment: Thanks, I actually did this: `When spying on elements other than the <body>, be sure to have a height set and overflow-y: scroll; applied.`